# Golang grouping files of same extension

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I am making a basic program in Golang which outputs the number of files in your current directory and how many lines of code each file contains:

I am trying now to group the files that have the same extension and I run into problems.
so, what I did is declaring a map of strings as keys and a slice of strings as value:

to store the extname as a key with its files in that slice

```
var m = make(map[string][]string)
```

I first receive in "group" function a slice of files read by the program (q argument) which looks like this:

```
[.gitignore README.md cmd\root.go example.go eyeball.exe go.mod go.sum main.go utils\utils.go]
```

Then I operate on that slice of files:

```
func group(q []string) {

    var ext string
    var checkedext []string

    for _, val := range q {
        ext = strings.Split(val, ".")[1]
        for _, foo := range q {
            secext := strings.Split(foo, ".")[1]
            if ext == secext {
                if !contains(checkedext, ext) {
                    addtogroup(ext, foo)
                    checkedext = append(checkedext, ext)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

}

func contains(s []string, item string) bool {
    for _, el := range s {
        if el == item {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

var m = make(map[string][]string)


func addtogroup(ext, file string) {

    var subgroup []string
    if val, ok := m[ext]; ok {
       val = append(val, file)
    } else {
        subgroup = append(subgroup, file)
        m[ext] = subgroup
    }
}
```

and when I print the map It outputs this:

```
map[exe:[eyeball.exe] gitignore:[.gitignore] go:[cmd\root.go] md:[README.md] mod:[go.mod] sum:[go.sum]]
```

However, the above output is wrong because I have 3 .go files.

I know that range iterates through a copy of the map and I can't reference it by pointer because the map is a reference itself, I can't find a way around it,
I thought of making this:

```
var m = make(map[string]*Data)
```

but I don't know If it's the best thing to do or not

I tried hard to explain what I want my program to do and what it does instead so, If I am missing any details just point me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you add an element to a slice (that's inside the map), you have to reassign the result slice, because `append()` returns a new slice header that contains the appended items:

```
if val, ok := m[ext]; ok {
   val = append(val, file)
    m[ext] = val
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Or simply:

```
m[ext] = append(m[ext], file)
```

This also handles if `ext` is not yet in the map, because then `m[ext]` will be the zero value of the value type (which is `[]string`), and the zero value is the `nil` slice. You are allowed to append to the `nil` slice.

Also to get the extension, use [`filepath.Ext()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Ext).

Your `group()` function can be as simple as this:

```
func group(names []string) map[string][]string {
    m := map[string][]string{}
    for _, name := range names {
        ext := filepath.Ext(name)
        ext = strings.TrimPrefix(ext, ".")
        m[ext] = append(m[ext], name)
    }
    return m
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(group([]string{"x\\a.txt", "b.txt", "c.go"}))

fmt.Println(group([]string{"a.go", "xy\\b.go", "c.txt"}))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mFSUampaTT-)):

```
map[go:[c.go] txt:[x\a.txt b.txt]]
map[go:[a.go xy\b.go] txt:[c.txt]]
```

See related questions:

[How to update map values in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716852/how-to-update-map-values-in-go/42716918#42716918)

[How to categorize list of objects based on a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734153/how-to-categorize-list-of-objects-based-on-a-parameter/59735013#59735013)

Comment: Look how many lines of code I wrote to get this basic feature done and to your solution :)

Comment: Can I do it using the struct (Data) I showed earlier in the question If so, could you tell me how? and If it will be a better approach or not?

Comment: @MohamedTarek You didn't show how you image that, but a slice is a small struct that contains a pointer to a backing array, so it's similar to using `*Data`. I think my presented solution is pretty clear, compact and efficient. I don't know exactly what more you'd want to do with `Data`.